# I am trying to run the following java code in netbeans but when i run the code i get thr following exceptions

Tags: java

I am trying to run the following java code in netbeans but when i run the code i get thrown following exceptions

```
package b;
public class B {
    int i;
}

class C extends B {
    int i;
    C(int a,int b) {
        super.i=a;
        i=b;
    }
    void show() {
        System.out.println("i in superclass:"+super.i);
        System.out.println("i in subclass:"+i);
    }
}

class UseSuper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C subOb=new C(1,2);
        subOb.show();
    }
}
```

> Error: Main method not found in class b.B, please define the main 
>             method as:
>             public static void main(String[] args)
>             or a JavaFX application class must extend 
>             javafx.application.Application
>             C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-
>             snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>             BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
>           "

Comment: The `main` method is expected to be in `B` class, since that's the `public` class of your source file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class have a public modifier then the file name should be with the same name as B.java, So you are executing "B" file which doesn't have any main method. Execute the file "UseSuper" and make it public as well which is a good practice.

**Error: Main method not found in class b.B, please define the main**

Below I have executed the same program:

```
C:\Users\A634681>java UseSuper
i in superclass:1
i in subclass:2
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `UseSuper` class public instead `B`, and rename file to UseSuper.java :

```
package b;

class B  {
    int i;
}

class C extends B {
    int i;

    C(int a,int b) {
        super.i=a;
        i=b;
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println("i in superclass:"+super.i);
        System.out.println("i in subclass:"+i);
    }
}

public class UseSuper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C subOb=new C(1,2);
        subOb.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the following exceptions:Error: Could not find or load main class usesuper.UseSuper
C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package b;

public class B  {
    int i;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    C subOb=new C(1,2);
    subOb.show();
  }
}

class C extends B {
         int i;

C(int a,int b) {
    super.i=a;
    i=b;
}

void show() {
    System.out.println("i in superclass:"+super.i);
    System.out.println("i in subclass:"+i);
  }
}
```